# Homology group of weird space using Mayer-Vietoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

For the space $X$ depicted above compute the homology groups.

**Attempt**: I tried to use Mayer Vietoris with $A=X/D_1$ and $B=D_2$ ($D_1$ a disc at the center and $D_2\supset D_1$) getting an exact sequence $0\to H_2(X)\to\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(A)\oplus H_1(B)\to H_1(X)\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to H_0(X)\to 0$ and I know $H_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ by connectedness. Obviously $H_1(B)=0$ so we get $0\to H_2(X)\to\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(A)\to H_1(X)\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$ and thus $H_2(X)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Now I am stuck. Can I use the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$ to conclude that $H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$? How do I get $H_1(X)$ then?

Specifically what is $H_1(A)$ and what is the map $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to H_1(A)$?

Comment: This weird space actually isn't weird at all, it has a very familiar shape. Note that you can effectively combine $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ into a single edge.

Comment: Indeed, cellular homology here is more comfortable: it has a natural CW complex structure with 1 point, 4 edges and 1 disk

Comment: @Thorgott you mean like a torus? Wouldn't that imply that the points connecting $(a,b),(b,c)$ are different but we want them to be the same point?

Comment: No, I'm just saying the concatenation of the three edges $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ does not serve a purpose different than a single edge in the usual identification of a torus with a square with opposite sides identified.

Comment: @Thorgott yes ok, I get that but does that mean it has the homology group of a torus then?

Comment: Homeomorphic spaces have the same homology, yes. But as for your attempt, there is a mistake since $\pi_1(X)$ does not have abalianization $\mathbb{Z}^4$. To get more information from the Mayer-Vietoris-sequence, you will have to compute the homology of $A$ and then figure out what exactly some of the induced maps look like.

Comment: @guidoar That's not the fundamental group of the torus. The picture in the question body is not the usual polygonal representation of a surface of genus 2.

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right. My bad!

Comment: @Thorgott but in the end if you are correct I should end up with $H_2(X)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: No, $H_2(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ for the torus.

Comment: @Thorgott my mistake I meant $H_1(X)$

Comment: Yes, $H_1(X)$ will be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. As for $H_1(A)$, try if you can see that it is homotopy-equivalent to some other familiar space.